# Design Rate limiter for outgoing http calls without discard

Tags: queue, microservices, rate-limiting, scalable

Requirement is to rate limit the outgoing http calls to an external service based on a unique client identifier in highly scalable distributed **microservice** architecture.

**Explaination**

Suppose my service name is ***penguin*** which is calling external service ***raven***. There are multiple instances of ***penguin*** service running. Only 1 instance of ***raven*** is running. Http request body from ***penguin*** to ***raven*** contains a parameter named *clientId*.

*List of ***clientId*** is **dynamic** and can grow in future*.

***penguin*** is called by an upstream service, say ***falcon***

So flow is ***falcon*** -> ***penguin*** -> ***raven***

There is no rate limit between ***falcon*** and ***penguin***

Now ***raven*** can accept only one request in 5 seconds which means any two http request with same *clientId* must have a gap of 5 seconds. If there are two requests within 5 seconds time window, penguin must have to wait to hit second request to respect 5 seconds time window for same *clientId*.

For example, request from ***penguin*** R1 with *clientId* **xyz** has been called to ***raven*** at 12:05 pm, R2 comes with same *clientId* **xyz** at 12:08 pm. Penguin must have to queue R2 and can only call ***raven*** on or after 12:10 pm. We can not drop R2, it must wait.

Looking for an appropriate design solution for this problem in the context of highly scalable microservice world.

Comment: Instead of directly calling raven, penguin can queue requests, and raven can read them at its own pace. Of course, that means that penguin has to send back "HTTP Accepted" as a response to requests from falcon, instead of "OK".